# Estimating the size of a java object on a 32 bit vm?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

If I have a class like:

```
Class A{
B b = new B();
int y;
int x;
}

Class B{
double x;
double y;
}
```

What will be the size of an object of Class A on a 32 bit VM/machine?

Comment: Many questions have already been asked and answered here on StackOverflow. Please use the search before posting a new question, you may find your answer instantly.

Answer (score -1):

My bet would be 128 bits.

64 bits as a long for the pointer to B.
32 bits each for the ints.

Whether the VM is 32 or 64-bit doesn't matter.